# C2065 Employee: необъявленный идентификатор

Tags: c++

**Factory.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Employee.h"

using namespace std;

class Factory
{
private:
    string name;
    int capacity;
    vector<Employee*> stack;
public:
    Factory();
    Factory(string name, int capacity);
    ~Factory();
    int GetCapacity();
    void ShowEmployeeList();
    string GetName();
    void virtual ShowFactoryInfo();
    string virtual GetType();
};
```

Ошибки:

C2065   Employee: необъявленный идентификатор   EmployeeManagment Factory.h 13
C2059   синтаксическая ошибка: >    EmployeeManagment   Factory.h   13

**Employee.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Enums.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include "Factory.h"

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
    string fio;
    int number;
    int age;
    int stage;
    int salary;
    vector<Factory*> workplace;

public:
    string GetFIO();
    int GetNumber();
    int GetAge();
    int GetStage();
    int GetSalary();
    void CalculateSalary(int);
    virtual string GetType();
    virtual void DisplayEmployee();
    Employee();
    Employee(string, int, int, int);
    ~Employee();
};
```

**Ошибки:**

C2065   Factory: необъявленный идентификатор    EmployeeManagment   Employee.h  20
C2059   синтаксическая ошибка: >    EmployeeManagment   Employee.h  20

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас циклическая зависимость - хедеры инклудят друг друга. Хотя бы один из двух `#include` нужно убрать, а лучше оба. Чтобы компилятор после этого не ругался на необъявленный идентификатор - добавить *предварительное объявление* соотвествующего класса: `class Employee;` и т. п.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что служащего  вообще не  нужно связывать с  вектором  фабрик. Это фабрика должна  агрегировать служащих. А если хочется, то служащего связать только с одной фабрикой.